# ANCOVA interpretation

Tags: interaction, interpretation, ancova

I have a continuous independent variable (`AGE_CONT`), a categorical independent variable (`EXP_CATER`, within subject, three categories) and one dependent variable. I conducted a repeated measure ANCOVA with `AGE_CONT` as a covariate.

The results showed no main effect of `EXP_CATER`, nor interaction between `EXP_CATER` and `AGE_CONT`. But there was a significant main effect of `AGE_CONT`.

My questions are related how to interpret these results:

1. Because previous ANOVA showed no main effect of `EXP_CATER` on DV, can I say `AGE_CONT` does not **moderate** the influence of `EXP_CATER` on DV? Or I need to conduct a moderation analysis to make such conclusion? I only can interpret the results like this: there is no influence of `EXP_CATER` on DV, even after **controlling** `AGE_CONT`?
2. Can I interpret the main effect of `AGE_CONT` as it has influence on DV? And then conduct a correlation analysis to find out the direction?
3. What does the interaction mean?

Comment: To whom it may concern: this question seems clear enough to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, EXP_CATER is your focal variable and AGE_CONT is a "between-subjects" to control for potential unwanted effects of AGE on DV. Then I agree with your final interpretation in 1 (sorry, I don't know what a moderation analysis is). I think 2. is correct (though maybe you suspected of that correlation and that is why you used the covariate) but of course your result in conditional on observed levels of EXP_CATER. A positive interaction would've meant that the differences among levels of EXP_CATER is conditional on the values of AGE_CONT (different DV-AGE slopes)